# How do I test with my resource files at Andrdoid Studio?

Tags: android, junit, gradle, android-studio, continuous-integration

I am using Android Studio and using test framework.

I want to use an image data as testing.

The test image should be located at SD card, I can add the image data to SD card img file through DDMS.

When using Version Control System (VCS) to realize Continuous Integration (CI) or team developing, I want to include the image to source file.

Surely I do not want to include the test image data to final apk file.

- src

  - androidTest

    - java
    - res <-- Do I put images here?
  - main

Comment: You could put to test assets and copy it before test to sd card